# Performing viewshed analysis from each pixel (now points) in raster and getting JSON out of it using QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, json, viewshed

My question can be divided in **3 steps** and I guess **I can answer 1.5** of them already.

To perform the viewshed analysis from every single pixel in a raster I will need:

- A viewshed plugin (which I am willing to use either the one from GRASS or [**QGIS plugin for visibility analysis**](http://www.zoran-cuckovic.from.hr/QGIS-visibility-analysis/)

Now the **3 steps are**:

- **STEP 1: Get the points layer from the raster**

This is my raster:
[image]
What I've done was used **Raster Pixels to Points** tool:
[image: Raster Pixels to Points]
and then I got this layer:
[image]
which I think it's was I need for step 2.

- **STEP 2: Perform Viewshed Analysis for each Point**

As I said I would use one of those plugins/tools, but since the one use in GRASS requires to select one pixel at a time, I was trying to used the other one (QGIS plugin for visibility analysis).
So here is the configuration of the tool that I used:
[image]

--> *From this point on I have problem achieving what I wanted* <--

After I run it I have an error associated with the fact that I am not passing some fields ( which I think are also fundamental, **observ_hgt** and **radius**) and I don't know either where to put them...
[image]

I even tried to add the fields observ_hgt with the value 1.5 and radius 2000 to each pixel (by clicking **Toggle Editing > Open Field Calculator**) but afterwards I got another error (as can be seen below):
[image]

From this point on I don't know how to proceed and even **Step 3** I don't know how would it be possible to achieve. But what I had in mind was to get an output like this...

```
{
  "70.24,214.22": {
    "visible_coordinates" : [ "70.23,214.24", "70.27,216.24",.... ]
  },
  "70.24,215.22": {
    "visible_coordinates" : [ "70.23,214.24", "70.27,216.24", .... ]
  },
  "70.24,216.22": {
    "visible_coordinates" : [ "70.23,214.24", "70.27,216.24", "70,4...." ]
  },
  .........
}
```

I said JSON but what I need is a way to get the information easily using python of knowing this: given a pixel coordinate, from which pixels is it visible? (something like reverse viewsheding, hope this isn't that dumb to say)

How do I solve Step 2?

Comment: If you are stuck on Step 2 then that is what I think you should focus this question on. You can always ask about step 3 in another question.